# How to read x and y coordinates of an element in my view SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, position, coordinates

In my view I will have a view that will hold a question that will look something like

"This is a question, the answer is __________"

and below will be a list of clickable buttons with the answers. When the user clicks the correct answer I want the button to move itself to the position of the ________ on the screen. So its essentially filling it in.

I will work out the visual but I need some way to read the x and y coordinates of the __________ text element so I can tell the button where to go to. The position of the blank space will be dynamic so it could be different for each question.

Is that possible and how would I do that?

Comment: https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/